# Relação entre structs em C

Tags: c, variáveis, struct

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

```
typedef struct Unidade{
    int cod;
} und;

typedef struct Produto{
    int cod;
    char nome[100];
    und unidade;
} prod;
```

Como podem ver tenho uma variável do tipo unidade dentro de produto. Como gravo nessa variável e como acesso ela?

Em `unidade` gravo assim: u

```
nidade.cod = 10;
```

Em `produto` ficaria como na hora de gravar nessa variável `unidade`? E como eu leria essa variável mais tarde?

Comment: Como está seu código que cria uma instância dessa estrutura?

Comment: no main esta assim  prod produtos[100]; //lista de produtos
 und unidades[20]; // lista de unidades

Comment: Edita a pergunta, coloca direitinho como tá.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente é

```
produto.unidade.cod = 10;
```

onde `produto` é a variável da instância.

A leitura seria feita assim:

```
produto.unidade.cod
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Basic.c).

Se o objeto for criado como ponteiro aí teria que usar o operador `->` no lugar de `.`.